# In Pandas, how to get the value_counts() of a Series containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` series `df.files` which looks like this:

```
In [79]: df.files
Out[79]:
0        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
1        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
2        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
3        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
4        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
5        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
6        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
7        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
8        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
9        [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
10       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
11       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
12       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
13       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
14       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
15       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
17       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
18       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
19       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
20       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
21       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
22       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
23       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
24       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
25       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
26       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
27       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
28       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
29       [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
                               ...                        
16487    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16488                                                   []
16489    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16490    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16491                                                   []
16492    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16493    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16494    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16495                                                   []
16496                                                   []
16497                                                   []
16498    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16499    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16500    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16501    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16502    [{'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/...
16503                                                   []
16504                                                   []
16505                                                   []
16506                                                   []
16507                                                   []
16508                                                   []
16509                                                   []
16510                                                   []
16511                                                   []
16512                                                   []
16513                                                   []
16514                                                   []
16515                                                   []
16516                                                   []
```

Some of the values are empty lists, while others are lists containing a single dictionary with a format similar to the following:

```
In [80]: df.files.loc[0]
Out[80]: 
[{'checksum': '9f6075f4c561792e48354277b46a6810',
  'path': 'full/80832b9fca82ce0f58f4d23c511e5a1d657c40e8.php?id=2968',
  'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=2968'}]
```

I would like to find out how many of the entries of `df.files` are actually empty lists. However, if I try `df.files.value_counts()`, I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. How might I go about solving this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert to `tuple` first if want use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
vc = df.files.apply(tuple).value_counts()
```

But if need only `length` of empty `lists` use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for count `lists`, then `sum` all `True`s of boolean mask:

```
l = (df['files'].str.len() == 0).sum()
```

If no `NaN`s values is possible use [IanS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702584/in-pandas-how-to-get-the-value-counts-of-a-series-containing-lists/44702618#comment76388326_44702637):

```
l = (df['files'].apply(len) == 0).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for empty lists, why use value_counts?

```
len([i for i in df.files if len(i) == 0])
```

Comment: Or `(df['files'].apply(len) == 0).sum()` (could be faster)

Comment: @IanS yeah you right. never used that before. now I def. will

Comment: hm, `df['files'].str.len()` is likely even faster (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a for loop to iterate through the list too:

```
for i in df.files:
    count = 0
    if len(i) == 0:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        pass
```